# plone.outputfilters.filters.resolveuid_and_caption: got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote'

Tags: plone

I have started to see this on old 3.3.x instance:

```
       'views': <zope.app.pagetemplate.viewpagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x1153346c>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 163, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 125, in render
  Module Products.Archetypes.ClassGen, line 56, in generatedAccessor
  Module wicked.fieldevent, line 29, in render
  Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 26, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 130, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 290, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 583, in subscribers
  Module wicked.fieldevent, line 16, in notifyFieldEvent
  Module zope.component._api, line 101, in getMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component._api, line 114, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component.registry, line 206, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 530, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module wicked.fieldevent.meta, line 78, in field_value
  Module Products.Archetypes.Field, line 1394, in get
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseUnit, line 100, in transform
  Module Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine, line 181, in convertTo
  Module Products.PortalTransforms.chain, line 51, in convert
  Module Products.PortalTransforms.Transform, line 192, in convert
  Module plone.outputfilters.transforms.html_to_plone_outputfilters_html, line 47, in convert
  Module plone.outputfilters, line 6, in apply_filters
  Module plone.outputfilters.filters.resolveuid_and_caption, line 103, in __call__
  Module sgmllib, line 95, in feed
  Module sgmllib, line 129, in goahead
  Module sgmllib, line 283, in parse_starttag
  Module sgmllib, line 314, in finish_starttag
  Module plone.outputfilters.filters.resolveuid_and_caption, line 349, in unknown_starttag
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote'
```

It apparently some kind of compatibility problem with Plone 3.3.x and plone.outputfilters which could be solved with proper pindowns. However I am not sure what components are involved and thus what's Known Good Set to fix this.

I'd like to get a temporary solution for this before getting all sites migrated, as old stuff should not just break down if you leave it unattended :(

Also the latest security fix might be involved.

Comment: outputfilters was not part of the hotfix. What version of plone.outputfilters are you using? I thought that package was meant for plone 4.

Comment: If it's meant for Plone 4 then it gets pulled into Plone 3 somehow. Version is plone.outputfilters 1.8. It should *not* appear in Plone 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have a few old 3.3.5 sites and just started seeing this error.  Pinning plone.outputfilters to version 1.6 seems to fix it so far.  I.e., in buildout.cfg

```
[versions]
...
plone.outputfilters = 1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet  you are using TinyMCE, this pulls p.outputfilters.

As with the Plone-3-series the default editor is Kupu, this changement can be the cause and apparently has been fixed in the Plone-core: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/9938

Quoting David Glick:
"For historical reasons, these transformations are implemented in both kupu and TinyMCE. This has been a maintenance problem, as bugfixes for these features in one of the packages usually don't get ported to the other."

You'll have to apply a patch according to these changements, I suppose.

Also this changement could be relevant as this topic concerns both, the core and the third-party-editor code:
https://github.com/plone/plone.outputfilters/commit/e5067c8ef1894d1017d6bc81c5969112676840d5#plone/outputfilters/filters/resolveuid_and_caption.py

Using the current unreleased dev-branch of p.outputfilters (1.9 by time of writing) could help, too.

Comment: I use TinyMcE 1.3beta... to get a working editor for IE. 1.3beta should be Plone 3.3 compatible but apparently this issue breaks 3.3 compatibility.

Comment: The recommended TinyMCE version with Plone-3 is '1.1.11'. Is your instance running or does the error actually break everything? I'll have to update my answer asap, to make more clear that the cause I suspect is, that someone inserted an image-caption with Kupu and now with Tiny it throws the error.

Comment: Yes, but I rather fix error with new TinyMCE than fight with old, unsupported TinyMCE, versions. So it really doesn't matter what the supported version is :(